# Using a web service to drop message onto an ActiveMQ Queue fails on failover

Tags: activemq-classic, soa, nms

I have a two activeMQ(5.6.0) brokers. They use a shared kaha database so only one can be 'running' at once.

I have a (asp.net) webservice that puts a message on a queue, locally if I start and stop the brokers the webservice fails over correctly

when I test with the brokers on seperate machines it sometimes works but often I get  "socketException: Connection reset" errors and the message is lost.

The connection string I am using is below. Note that I am aware NMS does not understand the priority backup command but I have left it there for the future.

```
failover:(tcp://MACHINE1:61616,tcp://MACHINE2:62616)?transport.initialReconnectDelay=1000&amp;transport.timeout=10000&amp;randomize=false&amp;priorityBackup=true
```

How can I make my fail over between brokers fool proof?

Comment: you have got some typos in your url : &amp; should be &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared Kaha database was on a simple share. Currently activeMQ (or windows) cannot reliably get or release the lock in this configuration. The shared database must sit on a 'real' SAN so that both instances of the queue software see the database as being on a local filestore not a network location.

See this page for more info http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html